# How to write text under Google pie chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using Google's charting code.

I wish to show a simple 3D pie chart with legend and title, but I also wish to write text under the chart. Something like this picture - how to do this?

[image]

Comment: just add a block element (e.g. `<div>`) under the chart element...

Comment: @Tal Angel Have you found the solution or not?